# modx revolution multiply values in cart

Tags: php, e-commerce, modx, modx-revolution

I didn't find anything suitable in the docs and tutorials: I use minishop2 and in my cart I display price and count like this:

```
[[+price]]  [[+count]]
```

but also I need to add total sum for the rows, which is price * count. How can I do this on modx without writing some special code?

Something like `[[+price]*[+count]]` - could I do something like this in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to work something out with Output Modifiers: http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/input-and-output-filters-(output-modifiers)

Example:

```
[[+price:mpy=`[[+count]]`]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can multiply placeholders like that. What you can do though, is to write a little snippet to do it for you:

```
[[!mySnippet? &value1=`[[+price]]` &value2=`[[+count]]`]]
```

Then the content of mySnippet

```
<?php

$output = $value1 * $value2;

return $output;
```